# Estimate 1-Norm of inverse diagonally dominant Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A=(a_{nm})^N_{n,m=1}$ with $$ \min\limits_n|a_{nn}| >  (N-1) * \max\limits_{m \neq n}|a_{nm}| $$
then $A$ is regular and 
$$
\lVert A^{-1} \lVert_1 \leq \left ( \min\limits_n|a_{nn}| -  (N-1) * \max\limits_{m \neq n}|a_{nm}| \right )^{-1}
$$
holds.

I already showed that A is regular by using, that $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant. Now I want to show that the estimate holds.

**Edit:**
So I found the following lemma in my lecture notes:
If $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant, then $A$ is regular and 
$$ \lVert A^{-1} \lVert_\infty \leq \max\limits_{1 \leq n \leq N} \left ( 
|a_{nn}| - \sum_{m \neq n} |a_{nm}| 
\right )^{-1} $$
My approach now is using the first equation to show, that $A^T$ is again strictly diagonally dominant. The second equation can then be easily achieved by some transformations of the third one.